# Streaming data processing with Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have events being pushed to Kafka from the App. 
Business design is so that for one interaction in the App maximum 3 events can be generated.
The events for one interaction have common ID.
My goal is to combine those three Events in one row in Delta table.
I'm doing 15 minutes timestamp based window aggregation.

And the issue is the following.
Let's say it's the period of 12:00 - 12:15.
Event A - timestamp = 12:14:30 
Event B - timestamp = 12:14:50 
Event C - timestamp = 12:15:50 
So Event C is in different time frame and hence it is not combined to A and B. 
I can check for each batch whether the ID exists already in delta table or not but I wonder if there is more elegant way to solve these cases.

Comment: you need to use sliding window: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#types-of-time-windows

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks, the issue with sliding window is that if later I want to make daily aggregation on top of my destination table, i'll have wrong numbers, because of the overlaps made by sliding windows. isn't that true?

Comment: it's really depends on how you combine your interactions, and how you do daily aggregations. For example, you can combine data and save timestamps, and then in the aggregation aggregate by these timestamps.

Comment: @AlexOtt thank you, your example feels good. I'll try to implement that way and come back here :)